# TapGesture in UITableViewCell causing other cells to have altered state

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm making my first iOS app and I have a UITableView with a list of UITableViewCells. Each UITableViewCells has two labels:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *upvote;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *downvote;
```

These labels each have a gesture recognizer. When the label is tapped, both label's have their alpha set to 0 through an animation.

```
-(void) handleSingleTapGesture: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UILabel *vote = (UILabel*)[gestureRecognizer view];
    AppCell *appCell = (AppCell*)vote.superview.superview;

    [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0 animations:^(void) 
    {
        appCell.upvote.alpha = 0;
        appCell.downvote.alpha = 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the cellForRawAtIndexPath method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath 
{
    AppCell *cell = (AppCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AppCell"];
    App *app (self.apps)[indexPath.row];

    /** setting the text/fonts/alpha for other labels I get from a HTTP POST request. Did not include the code since not relevant */

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTapGesture:)];

    cell.upvote.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:14];
    [cell.upvote setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell.upvote addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];

    *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTapGesture:)];

    cell.downvote.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:14];
    [cell.downvote setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell.downvote addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];

}
```

It works as it should. When I tap the text, they both disappear. However, it seems that as I scroll down some of the future cells don't have the UPVOTE/DOWNVOTE text.

I'm pretty confident that it has something to do with the reuse of cells but I do not know how to fix it.

I have looked up potential solutions and I can't seem to find much. The only thing I could find was that it was more efficient adding gesture recognizers to the `UITableView` instead of the `UITableViewCell`. I can't do that because I don't want an action to occur when the cell is tapped, only when one of the two labels is tapped.

If more information is required/there is a solution that I missed on StackOverflow please let me know.

Comment: Can you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, it likely has to do with the reuse of cells. The comment in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` methods says it handles the alpha but there is no setting of alpha in the method, so...

When a cell is reused, the `upvote` and `downvote` label alpha is whatever it was last set to, either implicitly (defaults to 1 when the `UILabel` is created) or explicitly (set to 0 by the gesture handler).

You'll need to keep track of the votes for each cell, and set the alpha appropriately in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: I meant that it handles the alpha (by setting the initial alpha). Sorry for the confusion. Does that mean it should have something such as `if (voted) app.upvote.alpha = 0; else app.upvote.alpha = 1;`?

Comment: @WilliamBingHua - yes, something like that should work.